# How to Save .url files?

Tags: java, android, file

I want to create an app that is able to save urls in form of [.url files](https://fileinfo.com/extension/url), in the same way as some browsers do it, but on android. I intend it to work like those bookmark shortcuts that you can add to your homescreen. So these .url files will open a specific url even when clicked, even from a file explorer.
I searched the net for a solution but was unable to. I'll be really grateful if anyone could guide me for the same.
Thanks in advance.